# use enum as a model to create a new object?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum as follows:

```
export enum TableViewTypes {
    user = 'users',
    pitching = 'pitching',
    milestones = 'milestones',
    mediaList = 'mediaList',
    contacts = 'contacts'
}
```

and I need to use it to dynamically create and object so something like this:

```
const newObject = {[keyof TableViewTypes]: false};
```

with an expected output of:

```
newObject = {
    user: false,
    pitching: false,
    milestones: false,
    mediaList: false,
    contacts: false
}
```

currently typescript complains about this...

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function that makes a new object and fills its properties with a value you specify, using keys from an existing object:

```
function fillProps<T, V>(t: T, v: V) {
  const ret = {} as {-readonly [K in (string & keyof T)]: V};
  (Object.keys(t) as (string & keyof T)[]).forEach(k => ret[k]=v);
  return ret;
}

const newObject = fillProps(TableViewTypes, false);
```

I'm pretty sure that at runtime this will evaluate to what you want, and the compiler will interpret it as of the type:

```
const newObject: {
    user: boolean;
    pitching: boolean;
    milestones: boolean;
    mediaList: boolean;
    contacts: boolean;
}
```

Hope that helps.  Good luck.